# I tried to implement collision and my game now refuses to load

Tags: java

I'm new to coding in Java and I'm trying to code a basic collecting items game but when I tried implementing collision the code the game now just entirely refuses to load and I can't figure out why. No specific code please because it's for a course. It was working before I added the collection function but I cannot work out exactly what broke it. All that the error box says is >NullPointerException. Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).

**Code**

```
Billy player;
Orb orb1, orb2, orb3, orb4, orb5;
CountDown timer;
int orbscollected=0;
PImage background;
int bgX=0;
final int playing=0;
final int finished=1;
int gamestate=playing;

void setup(){
  size(1000, 600);
  background=loadImage("background.jpg");
  background.resize(width,height);
  player=new Billy(height/2);
  orb1=new Orb(850, 500);
  orb2=new Orb(850, 400);
  orb3=new Orb(850, 300);
  orb4=new Orb(850, 200);
  orb5=new Orb(850, 100);
  timer = new CountDown(60);
}

void draw(){
  if (gamestate==playing){
    image(background, bgX, 0);
    player.render();
    orb1.render();
    orb2.render();
    orb3.render();
    orb4.render();
    orb5.render();
    text(timer.getRemainingTime(), 10,10);
    if (timer.getRemainingTime() == 0){
      gamestate = finished;
    } 
    if (player.collected(orb1)==true && player.collected(orb2)==true && player.collected(orb3)==true && player.collected(orb4)==true && player.collected(orb5)==true){
      gamestate = finished;
    }
      
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  if (key==CODED){
    if (keyCode == UP && player.y > 0)
    player.y -=5;
    else if (keyCode == DOWN && player.y < height-20)
    player.y +=5;
    else if (keyCode == RIGHT && player.x < width-20)
    player.x +=5;
    else if (keyCode == LEFT && player.x >0)
    player.x -=5;
  }
}

class Billy {
  
  int x = 50 ;
  int y;
  int counter;
  Boolean collected;
  PImage img = loadImage("Old_hero.png");
  PImage img2 = loadImage("Old_hero2.png");
  
  Billy(int y) {
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  void render() {
    if (counter < 10) {
      image(img, x, y);
    } else if (counter < 20) {
      image(img2, x, y);
    } else {
      counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
  }
  
  Boolean collected(Orb orb){
    if (player.x == orb.x && player.y == orb.y) {
    collected=true;
    }
    return collected;
    
  }
   
}    

class Orb {
  
  int x;
  int y;
  int counter;
  
  PImage img1 = loadImage("mm_yellow.png");
  
  Orb(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  void update() {
    move();
    render();
  }
  
  void move() {
    x -= (0);
  }
  
  void render() {
    if (counter>0){
      image(img1, x, y);
    }
    
    counter++;
  }
}


class CountDown
{
 private int durationSeconds;

 public CountDown(int duration)
 {
 this.durationSeconds = duration;
 }

 public int getRemainingTime() //return the seconds left on the timer or 0
 { //millis() processing command, returns time in 1000ths sec since program started
 return max(0, durationSeconds - millis()/1000) ;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, post the exact exception stack trace so the community can better understand how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that sticks out directly is the return value of your collected method.
If the player is not on the orb coordinates then you're returning null and that's most likely where your exception is coming from.

Change the *collected* variable to a boolean or initialize it to false on creation.